# PostgreSQL-Server doesn´t start

Tags: postgresql

I would like to use PostgreSQL locally on my computer and have installed
it. I use Windows 7.

I am not able to start the PostgreSQL-Server. When using the "Start Server"-program,
I get the following output in the dos command window:

Start DoCmd(net start postgresql-8.4)...

System error 2 (my translation)

System cannot find the specified file. (my translation)

Please ask, if I should give additional infos.

Comment: Maybe the PostgreSQL service can not find the required DLL files in the path environment variable for it's login account?

Comment: Sometimes I have seen this message ("System cannot find file") when the service account executable cannot find the DLL files it's dependent on, either because they are really missing, or the EXE cannot find them through the PATH environment variable. A simple way to check the first possibility is to use the Microsoft tool Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/). The second possibility can be checked by logging in as "postgres" (or using the RunAs command), execute the "PATH" command at the Command Prompt console window and check if the PostgreSQL "bin" directory is included.

Comment: Ok, I used the dependencywalker on the file PG_CTL.EXE and got a warning, that the file ieshms.dll cannot be found

Comment: I think that "pg_ctl.exe" is only a starter program - it actually starts "postgres.exe", which should have access to DLL files such as SSLEAY32.DLL, LIBEAY32.DLL, and others (depending on your system, of course). Under W7 it might have something to do with execution rights to do also, but I'm using WXP so I cannot tell how it really works.

By the way, I do not think that "ieshms.dll" is a real problem, since it is delay-loaded and probably not necessary for the PostgreSQL server start-up.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting it from your Services Applet of Control Panel.

Comment: You should check the Event log for Application Errors pertaining to that. I think there are also events for Services